# php validate integer [updated]

Tags: php, equality

**Read B**

**B *(new)*:**

I need to validate if variable is integer, I've tried all the available built-in functions or helpful tips, but the only best solution would be `regex` which I don't want to use this time.

also `filter_var` is not best because it also filters data, but I want to only validate it.

```
123
-123
'123'
'-123'
```

these inputs to be only `true`, `false` otherwise

I've tried many different options:

```
ctype_digit("-123"); // false - doesn't work
is_int('123'); // false 
filter_var('   123 ', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) !== false; // true - doesn't work
```

**A *(old)*:**

I'll give quick example:

```
$a = "\n  \t 34 3"; // string(9)

$aint = intval($a); // int(34)

var_dump($a == $aint);
```

result:

```
bool(true)
```

call me noob but can you tell me why/how does these variables do pass equalization test?

What I want to achieve is to check if `'1989'` equals `1989` would be true, but not any other case. ex: `'1989 '` should not pass the test. Also I don't want to use `regex`.

Comment: `===` this is helpless here, it would always be `false` because most cases I'd convert from string. I'll update question

Comment: How about `(string) $a === (string) $b`?

Comment: I like this (`$a === (string) $aint` this would do the trick), but it would require too much conversion, nope?

Comment: @NikiC but anyway that would not work if `'+123'` given

Comment: `is_numeric($a) && $a == intval($a)` should do the trick.

Comment: @shudder that way `+0123.45e6` returns `true` also, that I don't want to...

Comment: @GeorgeGarchagudashvili Maybe FILTER_VALIDATE_INT would help? It allows you to parse a string into an integer and specify certain options about what formats are allowed. But anyway, this is just guesswork as you did not specify just what exactly you want to allow and what you don't.

Comment: Your example (passed as string) returned false for me (php5.4). If you pass it as expression then it's technically an integer just like `$a = 1 + 1;` and that means your value is not `1 + 1` anymore but `2`.

Comment: @NikiC I did specify what I want to pass the test and what does not.

Comment: @shudder you are right, but if we say `+0123.45e6` is ok, then `'+0123.45e6'` also should be OK regarding the example `123` and `'123'`, in that case it would be OK to allow +0123.45e6

Comment: `+0123.45e6` is an int, just in scientific notation. I suggest you edit your question to be more specific. Otherwise this becomes a fishing question where requirements are only discovered and narrowed down after posing answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to thank you all for time, helping.

I've came up with the solution:

```
$filtered = filter_var($var, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
return $filtered !== false && (string) $filtered == $var;
```

This was most optimal solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you compare a number with a string or the comparison involves numerical strings, then each string is converted to a number and the comparison performed numerically.

References:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php
http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion

Comment: thats the point, thanks, but I've updated question, to help me find easier way to validate int

Comment: You should compare it with `===` and `!==` instead of `==` and `!=`.

Comment: I know that also does type match, but it will not help here

Comment: @GeorgeGarchagudashvili about your updated question: `$a = "1989 ";`
`$aint = intval($a);`
`var_dump(1989 === $aint && $a === "" . $aint . "");`
Would something like this work?

Comment: If there can be only spaces, ... You could use [trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php).

Answer (score 0):

The following easy trick would work (where 123*123=15129).

```
function checkInt($n) {
    return $n*$n==15129;
}
```

This will return true for '123', '-123', 123 and -123, and will return false for all other inputs $n.

Comment: `'123'` is just example man, you don't understand the subject well. thanks anyway